# Dell T3600 UEFI - Setup shows black screen, Windows boots only legacy

Tags: boot, uefi, workstation

I've had a Dell Precision T3600 (used / refurbished) for about two years now which is out of support. I want to reset and reinstall and pass it on to someone else because I replaced it with a newer one.

After full-trimming the SSD (SATA) and reinstalling windows it does not boot. (my usual workflow: boot linux usb, blkdiscard, boot windows usb, install win 10 with auto partitioning, done, easy.)

It can't find the OS.

I have to manually choose legacy boot instead of UEFI from the boot menu to start Windows which should not be the case.

So I wanted to reset the UEFI Settings and reconfigure it just in case I made a mistake years ago. After hitting F2 I get the message "The PC is entering setup..." or something similar but the next screen is only black, no setup, nothing.

Those are my two problems: UEFI does not show, Windows does not boot properly.

I didn't have these Problems on this workstation when I got it and didn't have any problems setting up my new one months ago.

Status Code with the black screen is 1, 2, 3, -. This is shown right before boot, also during the boot menu if I press F12. If it stays (according to the manual) the problem is "Something else", please check the graphics card, hard disk, connections and power, make sure the OS is able to boot. But the OS can boot, at least in legacy mode.

I can use Windows, I can put artificial pressure on the system, etc. I just can't access the System setup or boot using UEFI.

In my experience (and if I remember correctly) this is the last status code before the boot handover (1, 2, 3, - (current hang) -> 1, 2, 3, 4 (all on, handover to OS) -> -, -, -, - (all off, handover ok, windows loads))

Same with F12 when I open the boot menu and then want to go to setup.

F12 and running System diagnostics yield no problem, everything OK. Same when running Support Assist.

Same after resetting NVRAM when the system asks me to reset the clock I can't enter the setup.

I reset the NVRAM using the jumper on the board and by removing (and checking the voltage on) the battery (which reads ~3.13v, don't have a replacement currently, but I think this should be fine.)

System Firmware is Version A18, which is the latest for the service tag. There is no newer version.

There was a known Bug before 14 where at least a similar behaviour could appear if I read correctly.

I unplugged the SSD (SATA) (Power and Data) to see what happens -> The F12 Boot menu still shows the Boot option for the SSD (UEFI and Legacy). Below UEFI it shows "Windows Boot Manager" which I think could be fine even without a drive because I remember this could be a Option available from UEFI Setup, but below "Legacy" in my opinion it should not be able to display the correct device name ("Samsung 860 EVO" something), but it does without connected device.

At least after I unplugged the SSD, removed the power cord and battery it should have forgotten everything. On the other hand in the manual it says NVRAM which I understand real non-volatile memory which (depending on the kind of chip) might be able to survive total power loss including battery.

It somehow felt like a corrupted UEFI at first which the workstation should detect on its own though (IMHO). I booted the new Win 10 (F12 -> legacy) to manually install the same Firmware version over the current one. installed perfectly, no issues, install was OK. Still same problem: System Setup not visible on screen or not loaded or whatever and windows can not boot on its own.

Maybe because of this issue the Windows installation was not able to write the UEFI boot correctly?

When I use F12 and select Windows Boot Manager the screen is black and the code is stuck at 1, 2, 3, -, so it can't boot and again I assume the UEFI settings could not be written by Windows Setup.

I searched for this issue and the most relevant option was to update the Firmware, which is the most recent already.

I had BitLocker active before I discarded the whole SSD. I can't remember if I set a UEFI Admin password, but I usually do, but can't remember for this workstation. But I removed the Password jumper & booted without it in one of my attempts with this problem.

I have no idea what this issue is and how to solve it but I need to pass the computer next week and this is not a state I can give this workstation to another person.

Thanks for any ideas or solutions, any help or recommendations.

Have great holidays.

Comment: Sounds like your booted the Windows installation medium in legacy mode, which has led you to a legacy Windows installation. Check `fdisk -l` to confirm.

Comment: Also keep in mind Windows strinctly requires GPT for UEFI mode and conversely MBR ("msdos") for Legacy. Knowing you're already using a Linux live session you can (and probably should have) prepared the drive in advance by using Gparted > Device menu > Create new partition table, select "GPT". And then change the UEFI settings to allow UEFI only / disable CSM/Legacy/"BIOS" mode to assure the installer is booting in the proper UEFI mode. As commented above, how it boots is how it installs.

Comment: Thats more or less what I assume. Further on I assume I need to switch from Legacy to UEFI in the System setup, which I, as stated, can not access. Which leads to the core point of the question. Why does my System setup not work anymore and how do I fix it?